# convertFromHTML returns a null response | draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am sure I am doing something wrong. However, a simply empty html tag is creating a problem with convertFromHTML call.

```
convertFromHTML("<p>  </p>"); // returns null
```

Where as:

```
convertFromHTML("<p>empty</p>"); // returns a valid object.
```

Any thought son why it might be happening?

Answer (score 7):

> `convertFromHTML("<p>  </p>"); // returns null`

I'll assume "returns null" is meant literally in which case updating to the most recent `draft-js` version should fix the problem.

Here's my example
running

- `create-react-app` v1.5.2
- `draft-js` v0.10.5

`console.log(convertFromHTML('<p>  </p>'))`

[image: console log of convertFromHTML]

There is a "valid" object, but the `contentBlocks` property is `null`, which means we cannot create a valid `ContentState` as you'll get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentBlocks' of null
```

> Any thoughts on why it might be happening?

**Short Answer:** The HTML node needs text.

**In-Depth Answer:**

All of the following code is adapted from the most recent version of `draft-js` [source](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/4c4465f6c05b6dbb9eb769f98e659f917bbdc0f6/src/model/encoding/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js) at the time of this writing (commit 4c4465f). Some sections of methods are left out for brevity.

The method `convertFromHTMLtoContentBlocks` is what's called by this module and it has a few main steps:

1. process the html string
2. create a DOM from the string
3. produce blocks from the DOM
4. Mapping the blocks to the `contentBlocks` object

**1) Processing the string to a DOM**
The html gets processed by a method `getChunkForHTML` the output from which the `contentBlocks` is created.

```
const convertFromHTMLtoContentBlocks = (
  html: string,
  DOMBuilder: Function = getSafeBodyFromHTML,
  blockRenderMap?: DraftBlockRenderMap = DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap,
): ?{contentBlocks: ?Array<BlockNodeRecord>, entityMap: EntityMap} => {

  const chunkData = getChunkForHTML( // processing our html string into chunkData
    html,
    DOMBuilder,
    blockRenderMap,
    DraftEntity,
  );

  // use the chunkData to create contentBlocks
  const {chunk, entityMap} = chunkData;
  const contentBlocks = convertChunkToContentBlocks(chunk);

  return {
    contentBlocks,
    entityMap,
  };
};
```

Inspecting `getChunkForHTML`, we see that the white-space is trimmed to `<p></p>` and passed to `DOMBuilder`. The DOM created by `DOMBuilder` is converted into blocks by `genFragment`, prettied and returned as `chunk`.

```
const getChunkForHTML = (
  html: string,
  DOMBuilder: Function,
  blockRenderMap: DraftBlockRenderMap,
  entityMap: EntityMap,
): ?{chunk: Chunk, entityMap: EntityMap} => {
  html = html  // the string is trimmed
    .trim()
    .replace(REGEX_CR, '')
    .replace(REGEX_NBSP, SPACE)
    .replace(REGEX_CARRIAGE, '')
    .replace(REGEX_ZWS, '');

  const safeBody = DOMBuilder(html); // create DOM from trimmed html
  if (!safeBody) {
    return null;
  }

  const fragment = genFragment( 
    entityMap,
    safeBody,   // use DOM to create blocks in genFragment
    OrderedSet(),
    'ul',
    null,
    workingBlocks,
    -1,
    blockRenderMap,
  );


  let chunk = fragment.chunk;
  const newEntityMap = fragment.entityMap;

  // rest of method
  return {chunk, entityMap: newEntityMap};
};
```

**2) Create DOM from string**
If we inspect the `DOMBuilder` method (alias for `getSafeBodyFromHTML`) ([source](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/4c4465f6c05b6dbb9eb769f98e659f917bbdc0f6/src/model/paste/getSafeBodyFromHTML.js)) in the debugger, we see that we get a DOM node with these properties:

```
innerHTML: "<p></p>"
innerText:""
```

**3) Generating Blocks from the DOM**
The output of `DOMBuilder` is an argument to `genFragment` as `safeBody`. This method processes the DOM tree into blocks. Given that our DOM contains no text, the object returned from `genFragment` has the property: `text: ""`.

[image: genFragment chunk]

**4)Mapping the blocks to contentBlocks**

The last call in the `convertFromHTMLtoContentBlocks` is

`const contentBlocks = convertChunkToContentBlocks(chunk);`:

```
const convertChunkToContentBlocks = (chunk: Chunk): ?Array<BlockNodeRecord> => {
  if (!chunk || !chunk.text || !Array.isArray(chunk.blocks)) {
    return null;
  }
  // rest of method
}
```

clearly, at this point `chunk.text` returns `false` and thus `contentBlocks` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem and solved it using draft-js v0.10.4.
Hope this will work for you as well :)